# How to stop a command during execution discord.py

Tags: python, bots, discord

```
@client.command()
async def spam(ctx):
  while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    await ctx.send("spam")
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
      if message.content == "!stop":
        # stop spamming
```

---

I want the code to stop spamming but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example using `wait_for`:

```py
@client.command()
async def spam(ctx):

    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

    stopped = False
    await ctx.send("spam")
    while not stopped:
        try:
            message = await client.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=2)
            stopped = True if message.content.lower() == "!stop" else False
        except asyncio.TimeoutError: # make sure you've imported asyncio
            await ctx.send("spam")
    await ctx.send("spam finished!")
```

---

**References:**

- [`Client.wait_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for)
- [`Message.author`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.author)
- [`Message.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.channel)

Comment: this worked thank you -  im new to discord bots and probably should have read a bit more into it before experimenting anyway thanks

Comment: @thepostyboi No worries, glad you got it working. If you wouldn't mind, please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), as it could help others that are looking for the solution! Good luck with the rest of your bot :)

Comment: i accepted the answer, sorry i'm new to this website

Comment: @thepostyboi No problem, hope you get comfortable around here :^) If you haven't already, you can check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)! Happy coding!